How to suppress a deprecation warning from a Play Framework routes file
I have a Play Framework application where the routes file uses a deprecated controller method:
GET    /my-endpoint/this-is-deprecated    com.example.app.controllers.MyController.getThisIsDeprecated

package com.example.app.controllers

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}

@Singleton
class MyController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {
  @Deprecated
  def getThisIsDeprecated = // Implementation goes here
}

I want this deprecated method to be called until my clients migrate their implementations to no longer use it.  At that point, I'll remove the endpoint and delete the deprecated method.
When compiling the project, I get a deprecation warning since the routes file references a deprecated method:
[warn] /Users/Me/my-project/src/main/resources/routes:699:1: method getThisIsDeprecated in class MyController is deprecated
[warn] GET    /my-endpoint/this-is-deprecated    com.example.controllers.MyController.getThisIsDeprecated
[warn] /Users/Me/my-project/src/main/resources/routes:699:1: method getThisIsDeprecated in class MyController is deprecated
[warn] GET    /my-endpoint/this-is-deprecated    com.example.controllers.MyController.getThisIsDeprecated
[warn] two warnings found

I do not want the warning to be output with the build.  However, I do want other deprecated method usages in my project to be warned.
If this were Scala code, I would use @nowarn("cat=deprecation").  However, the routes file is not Scala, so this doesn't work.
How can I suppress just this one deprecation warning?

You can filter out warnings to exclude those coming from target/* for instance. But I'd argue : what's the value of having the method deprecated as nobody else than your own component is gonna use it anyway as it's a controller method?

(To be clear: there's a Scala flag to exclude warnings/errors from some files pattern. I don't have it right now but you can look in the documentation.)

@GaëlJ Marking it as deprecated makes it obvious to future maintainers of the code that the method isn't intended to be used for new code, and it should be reviewed for deletion in the future after checking whether no more clients/users call it.

For these cases, and more generally to avoid warnings/errors in generated code that we don't own, we use the following Scala compilation flag:
scalacOptions += "-Wconf:src=target/.*:silent"

Available in Scala 2 and Scala 3.3+.

The -Wconf compiler flag can be used to selectively silence warnings.
// Silence deprecation warnings for all usages of the controller method
scalacOptions +=
  """-Wconf:cat=deprecation&origin=com\.example\.app\.controllers\.MyController\.getThisIsDeprecated:silent"""

This compiler flag provides a number of filters to match only specific warnings for silencing.  Per the Configuring and Suppressing Warnings in Scala documentation, some particularly relevant filters for this specific goal are:


cat=deprecation filters according to the message category, for example deprecations […].
site=my\.package\..* filters on the site where the warning is triggered. […]
src=src_managed/.* filters warnings issued in a source file […].
origin=external\.package\..* filters on full name of the deprecated entity.


Using these filters, here are some different approaches to achieve the goal:
// Silence deprecation warnings for all usages of the controller method
scalacOptions +=
  """-Wconf:cat=deprecation&origin=com\.example\.app\.controllers\.MyController\.getThisIsDeprecated:silent"""

// Silence deprecation warnings for usages of any deprecated controller method
scalacOptions +=
  """-Wconf:cat=deprecation&origin=com\.example\.app\.controllers\..*:silent"""

I haven't figure out if there's a way to suppress deprecation warnings for just a single route in the routes file.  The site filter feels like it should be usable for this, but the fact that the route isn't a method in a Scala file makes it nonobvious how to specify a specific route, assuming it is even possible.
